# Перехват значений контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net

У меня есть веб-приложение на ASP.NET. В одном месте в контроллере получаются данные. Еще есть desktop-приложение. В desktop-приложении есть компонент WebBrowser, на котором отображается копия страниц веб-приложения. То есть, например, у приложения на ASP.NET есть начальная страница, на которую можно попасть по адресу http://localhost/Main/Hello
В desktop-приложении копия этой страницы отображается, если выполнить функцию

```
webbrowser.Navigate("http://localhost/Main/Hello");
```

Цель такая. В одно время в ASP.NET получаются данные, обрабатываются и передаются дальше. Мне нужно получить эти данные в desktop-приложении и запретить дальнейший переход "обрабатываются и передаются дальше".
То есть, например:

```
public ActionResult Hello()
{
    // Получаем данные, например в переменную Х
    string X = ...;
    // Обрабатываем
    // Пересылаем дальше
    Redirect(...);
}
```

Я пробовал обработку и пересылку дальше перенести в другой контроллер, куда данные посылать GET-запросом, вроде так:

```
public ActionResult Hello()
{
    // Получаем данные в переменную Х
    string X = ...;
    // Отправка переменной GET-запросом в другой контроллер
    string url = Url.Action("Priem", "Main", null, null, Request.Url.Host) + "?X=" + X;
    Redirect(url);
}

public ActionResult Priem(string X)
{
    // Приняли переменную и записали, например, в переменную Y
    string Y = X;
    // Обработка переменной Y
    Redirect(...);
}
```

При работе веб-приложения всё работает нормально, данные пересылаются. Дальше я хочу в desktop-приложении нужно перехватить эту переменную Х. Для этого я на событие компонента webbrowser вешаю проверку

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("Priem") != -1)
   {
      e.Cancel = true; // Запрет дальнейшего перехода
      // Обработка переменной, полученной с Url
   }
}
```

Но причина в том, что условие не выполняется, и такую ссылку оно не видит. Как мне тогда правильно это сделать или как по другому? webbrowser компонент должен обязательно быть. Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно перехватить ссылку, по которой `hello` перенаправляет пользователя, и предотвратить переход по ней (так, чтобы `priem` на сервере не вызвался)? К сожалению, это нельзя сделать с помощью webbrowser contol - он не позволяет перехватывать ответ типа `302 redirect`, который возвращает действие `hello`.

Можете попробовать заменить стандартный WebBrowser на [csEXWB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control), он позволяет просматривать заголовки ответа от сервера, и вы можете использовать это для предотвращения редиректа.

Аналог вашего запроса на английском SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019731/winforms-webbrowser-control-detect-redirections

Comment: спасибо. попробую покопать в эту сторону.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно что-то типа чата? В одном месте написали в другом отразилось?
Мне кажется, что Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону SignalR....
Вот тут есть пример работы http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/16.1.php

Comment: Да согласна с Олегом. Имхо плохо описан вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно поняла, то при запуске процедуры обработки из браузера, нужно предотвратить повторную обработку из другого приложения? Каким образом идентифицируется пользователь? Если по  ip или другому признаку, можно сохранять данные о запуске процесса с привязкой к этому пользователю, например, в переменных уровня приложения (application)

Comment: нет, обработка тут роли не играет. словом, нужно передать данные з веб-приложения на ASP.NET в десктопное приложение на C#

Comment: В любом случае Вам надо где-то эти данные сохранить, чтобы декстопное приложение могло их прочитать. Хранить их можно, например в переменных приложения, или вообще в БД. В сессии нельзя, так как это будут разные сессии.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы. Пока сделал по своему. Просто создал еще один контролер, который есть вроде как конечным. В него передаються данные и выводяться в отображение. А дальше, в дескотопном приложении можно через ивент Navigate i Navigating получить код этого отображения и извлечь из него данные. Теперь попробую использовать ваши предложения, возможно это упростит решение.